# The network path was not found When running from remote

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I Was upload my files,I put connection string in web config here is my script

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="it_ConnString"
 connectionString="Server=mssql.genesyssoftware.net;Database=it_db;User 
 ID=mgr;Password=mgr;Trusted_Connection=False;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

here is my complete web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<connectionStrings>
 <add name="it_ConnString" connectionString="Data 
   Source=genesyssoftware.net;Initial Catalog=it_db;User ID=xxxx;
   Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
<add key="it_ConnString" value="yourConnectionString" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" 
     targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0,
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, 
             Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, 
             Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add 
              <assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, 
               Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
              <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, 
               Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
              <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, 
               Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
              <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, 
               Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
              <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, 
               Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
              <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0,   
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, 
             Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" 
             type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, 
             Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET" 
         type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, 
         CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" 
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
         Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" 
         path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" 
         type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, 
         CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" 
         path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" 
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
         Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

here is login syntax :

```
 It_app.Login.cmdLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in   
         D:\ASPNET_TRAINING\It_app\It_app\Login.aspx.vb:14
```

and here is my login block syntax  :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Login
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Dim oConn As String =               
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("it_ConnString").ConnectionString
   Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(oConn)
   Dim oCmd As SqlCommand
   Dim oDtr As SqlDataReader
   Dim strSql, cUsr, cPwd As String

  Protected Sub cmdLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
        cUsr = UCase(txtusr.Text)
        cPwd = UCase(txtpwd.Text)
        strSql = "SELECT userlogin,password FROM userlst WHERE userlogin 
           = '" + cUsr + "' AND password = '" + cPwd + "'"
      myConn.Open()
        oCmd = New SqlCommand(strSql, myConn)
        oDtr = oCmd.ExecuteReader

        If Not (oDtr.Read) Then
            Response.Write("User does not exists")
    Else
        Response.Write("Login Success")
        End If
        ' myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

and here is the error complete messages :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The network path was not found
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5363103
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   It_app.Login.cmdLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\ASPNET_TRAINING\It_app\It_app\Login.aspx.vb:14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633690
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

But when i try to connect the database, i got that message error.

Does anyone can help me plz ...

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the Remote Registry service is stopped on the server where your code is getting executed. 
Go to the services and start the service

Comment: where i can found the service on server hosting ?

Comment: go to start>> run > type services.msc

Comment: i have start my remote registry service but the errors still occurs, i was upload my file and database to hosting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use your SQL Management Studio to test the remote SQL Server? if your local SQLMS failed to connect the remote sql server, the connectionstring will fail as well.

Comment: i contact my hosting, they said please check my scripts ... i confused which syntax should i check ?

Comment: if you don't mind, please let me see your web.config and login code block

Comment: change this <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" 
     targetFramework="4.0"> to <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" 
     targetFramework="4.0"> . Then login and let's see what error will be displayed

Comment: i've correct my connection string block in web config

Comment: and i've change my compilation debuf from false to true but i still got the same message. i found  " It_app.Login.cmdLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\ASPNET_TRAINING\It_app\It_app\Login.aspx.vb:14" what does it mean ... because i looking for the path in my code but i can't find it

Comment: why that path still occurs when i put my web to hosting ?

Comment: Try to look for the Port (1433) of the database, the hosting service will provide you a Port of database, try to use it. you also can find it in the Hosting Service Control Panel. Or you also can find the connectionstring there. https://sg.godaddy.com/help/find-your-connection-strings-3323

Comment: this is how to get connectionstring https://faculty.unlv.edu/jensen/html/Microsoft/VisualStudio/img/GoDaddyHostingConfiguration.png. try to remove this <add key="it_ConnString" value="yourConnectionString" />, and I recommend this <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

Comment: i try to detach my local database and running at localhost (my pc) with my domain as the server name in connection string, the result is worked. so what went wrong with my coding ?

Comment: are you using share hosting or dedicated server? if dedicated server, you just find the database name and use it (you don't need the domain name),  if you're using share hosting, you need a correct connectionstring from the hosting cpanel, or check the port 1433 or 1434 is open or not

Comment: i've remove the line <add key="it_ConnString" value="yourConnectionString" />. where i put your recommend line ?

Comment: i use share hosting, but how can i check that port ?

Comment: <directoryBrowse enabled="false" /> is already in your web.config file, just change true to false, this is to avoid user browse your server files. if share hosting, the ports should be already opened by default. uhm... let me check around

Comment: try this **Data Source=mssql10.pasarhosting.info** in your connectionstring

Comment: port 1433 has opened for my db, so what i have to do ?

Comment: i have change my datasource to Data Source=mssql10.pasarhosting.info imssql10.pasarhosting.info But that messages still occurs

Comment: hi, is there someone would try to help me how to resolve my problems ?

Answer (score 0):

I change my hosting server name connection string with mssql. added before my domain name then rebuild my app then publish. Don't know why it's work...